# MLFlow projects; bash: python: command not found

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, terminal, mlflow

I'm running MLflow Project for a model using following command from my ubuntu 20.04 terminal

```
mlflow run . --no-conda -P alpha=0.5
```

My system doesn't have conda or python (It does however have python3). So, I added alias for python using terminal

```
alias python='python3'
```

After which I could open python in terminal using `python`. However, I still got the same error

```
2021/11/21 08:07:34 INFO mlflow.projects.utils: === Created directory /tmp/tmpp4h595ql for downloading remote URIs passed to arguments of type 'path' ===
2021/11/21 08:07:34 INFO mlflow.projects.backend.local: === Running command 'python tracking.py 0.5 0.1' in run with ID 'e50ca47b3f8848a083906be6220c26fc' === 
bash: python: command not found
2021/11/21 08:07:34 ERROR mlflow.cli: === Run (ID 'e50ca47b3f8848a083906be6220c26fc') failed ===
```

How to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `python` to `python3` in the `MLproject` file to the resolve error.

```
command: "python3 tracking.py {alpha} {l1_ratio}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the command below in the terminal helped me:

```
$ sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

After installation, run the ML project and it should work.